I can't print on half an A4 sheet
In Jspdf, i need to print half an A4 sheet in portrait orientation.
This is my code:
let doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait', 
    unit: 'mm',
    format: [210, 148.5],
});

This causes the page to display horizontally.
I have also tried with:
let doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait', 
    unit: 'mm',
    format: [148.5, 210],
});

In this other way, it respects the orientation, but it is the other way around for me. That is, the width is the length and the length is the width.
How should I do?
